# Negative values after bitwise OR operation between two int values

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I am trying to perform a bitwise OR operation between two numbers: 650510336  and 2147483648 (`650510336 | 2147483648`)

As a result, I get the negative value: `-1496973312` instead of `‭2797993984`.

I thought I have an issue in my code, but if you send this command to the console in your browser, you can easily reproduce it.

```
console.log(650510336 | 2147483648)
```

Why doesn't this output 2797993984?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All bitwise operators in JavaScript, when used on numbers, treat their operands as/produce results of 32-bit *signed* integers… except for the `>>>` operator.

Since you want unsigned math, use an otherwise no-op logical right shift to reinterpret the signed result as unsigned:

```
console.log((650510336 | 2147483648) >>> 0)
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works fine